Unable to derive electric field of uniformly charged hemispherical shell using gauss law
I followed the below methodology to arrive at an answer,
Let the net charge on the hemispherical shell of radius $r$ be $Q$, then
Surface charge density = $Q/2πr^2 = σ$
Now, let us assume a spherical Gaussian surface of radius $R>r$ around the hemispherical shell, then
Net Flux = $E.dA = E.4πR^2...(1)$
{Since the Gaussian surface is spherical all the outgoing electric field line vectors will be along the area vector of the sphere}
By Gauss law, Net Flux =$(σ.2πr^2)/ε0...(2)$
Equating Equations (1) and (2),
$E = (σ.r^2)/(2R^2.ε0)$
Now, at centre $R = r$,
Electric field = $σ/2ε0$
This, however, is not the correct expression for the electric field due to a hemispherical shell.
So, please help me understand just where my lack of understanding lies that has resulted in this incorrect expression.

While Gauss's Law always holds, it is not always useful.
Gauss's Law states that
$$\int \vec{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{A} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}.$$
The calculation you did to find the electric field consisted of writing
$$E \int \vec{r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{A} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0},$$
while assuming that $$\vec{E} = E \vec{r}$$. This manipulation is only valid if it holds that
$$\vec{E} = E(r) \vec{r},$$
i.e., if the electric field is spherically symmetric.
However, in your case, the problem doesn't have spherical symmetry: it is a hemisphere, not a sphere. Hence, the upper portion should have a magnetic field different from the lower portion. The electric field might not be radial and it might depend on the angle at which you're pointing as well. Hence, the common trick we do with the Gauss law does not allow you to compute the electric field.
Gauss's Law still holds, it is just not useful for computing the electric field. Precisely because you don't have enough symmetry. If you have enough symmetry (and this is only in a handful of cases), you can do these tricks with the Gauss law to get to the electric field quite fast. This is not one of those cases. You will need to use Coulomb's law instead.

The problem is that, due to the assymmetry of the charged half-sphere, the electric field strength at the spherical Gaussian surface is not spherically symmetric and thus not constant. Therefore, you cannot use equation (1) to determine the flux. Gauss' law can only be used to easily obtain the electrical field in symmetric situations.
